# Calling function from another javascript inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript file named `loader.js` which contains a function called `initialize()`. I want to call this function via jQuery. This is my HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="loader.js" ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(document).on("click", ".link", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
      var a= $(this).text();
       window.initialize= function{
       };
      initialize(a);
      
       
       });
       });
      
         
     
     </script>
        </head>
        <body >
     <h1>welcome to my website </h1>
     <a href="#" class="link"> link1 </a>
     <a href="#" class="link"> link2 </a>
        <div id="main">
     
     </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is loader.js:

```
 function initialize(a) {
    $('#main').html= a;
         }
```

I do not  know what is wrong with this script, I have debug it jquery is working fine but funtion is not working correctly.
also I want that whenever the function is clicked again the div should be refreshed for example first it contain link1 but when link2 is clicked link1 should be removed inside the div how can i accomplish this task????

thanks in advance

Comment: include the loader.js in html

Comment: Include the `loader.js` file in your page, and uncomment the call to it. Also note that the `<script>` referencing jQuery should be *inside* the `<head>`, and you should use the `html()` method on the `$('#main')` jQuery object, not the `innerHTML` DOMElement method

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have done all what you said, but it is still not working i have updated the question

Comment: Get rid of `window.initialize = ...` and just call `initialize(a);` directly in the click handler function. Also it's `html(a)`. I would strongly suggest you read the jQuery documentation, as this is quite basic.

Answer (score 1):

You're not including the loader script. Add `<script src='loader.js'></script>` before the jQuery code.

The code in loader.js should be inside a jQuery(document).ready callback since it's now using jquery (the html method).

Also as @jiihoo pointed out you should use `$('#main').html(a);` instead of `$('#main').html = a;`.

Comment: OP has done that, and there are several other issues besides the scripts

Answer (score 0):

You should change to code of loader.js to this.

```
    function initialize(a) {
        $('#main').html(a);
    }
```

Heres the whole thing you could do.

Html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script src="loader.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
    <h1>welcome to my website </h1>
    <a href="#" class="link"> link1 </a>
    <a href="#" class="link"> link2 </a>
    <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Loader.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(document).on("click", ".link", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var a = $(this).text();
        initialize(a);
      });
    });

  function initialize(a) {
    $('#main').html(a);
  }
```